# Converting shapes from Adobe Illustrator to an ArcGIS Pro feature layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, convert, pdf, illustrator

I have a PDF file with both a basemap and a large number of paths on top of it, which I've edited in Adobe Illustrator.

How should I separate the basemap and add the paths as polygon features to a feature layer in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: The product MapPublisher is a purchased way by Avenza https://www.avenza.com/mapublisher/features/ (have used this in the past.)

Comment: For starters you need to know coordinate/projection information for your pdf map - some way to tie the picture to its location on Earth.

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to see and control the Object/layer list box in Illustrator (I don't remember what the list is called) and export groups of objects to different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question as I figured it out somewhat well.

As I mentioned, the map was quite complex and slow to edit, as it included both the basemap (with 1000+ paths) and the paths that I wanted to export in a same file.

I hand-picked each and every path to be exported, and separated them onto four different layers, depending on the type. I also separated the city's borders from the base map to be used as a control point.

Then, I deleted the original basemap from the file, and exported it as a DXF file, which I then imported to ArcGIS Pro as a CAD layer. I georeferenced the layer against the city's WMS map using corners from the city's borders at opposite ends as control points.

I however couldn't figure out how to convert the CAD feature layer to a normal feature layer to enable editing of the feature attributes, so I ended up exporting the whole map as a KML file to Google My Maps (which would have been its final destination anyways) and did the final editing and classification there.